# Having Issue With pulseaudio Under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, module, path, pulseaudio

I am having an issue that my pulseaudio application in my machine running **Ubuntu 16.04** cannot detect the location of the modules, and thus cannot load them and subsequently cannot detect any sound hardware (even though my sound cards are all detected, say, using this command: `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`). For instance, it cannot detect module-udev-detect unless I provide it with the absolute path in the default.pa file, and if I do so, I will be able to see a "Dummy Output" sound device, but that's not enough because module-alsa-card is not loaded. I have tried almost every solution out there, including the original Ubuntu wiki pages and those pages that direct me to remove, purge, and install the pulseaudio and alsa-base packages again. I believe the problem lies specifically in not finding the modules path in the first place, and I would like to know if I can fix this somehow?